# How to grab data and auto fill a form on change event using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**What I need**

I need when someone change my calendar, a php script should run in background and fetch some data and show it in the form fields accordingly. To do that, I have the following HTML code and Ajax script

```js
$("#normalShiftDate").change(function() {
  var FD = new FormData($('#dailyEditor')[0]);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "supervisorEditAjax.php",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: FD,
    success: function(result) {
      $('#normalShiftOperator').val(result["normalShiftOa"]);
      $("#normalShiftOperatorDuration").val(result["normalShiftOperatorDuration"]);
      $("#normalShiftPinCount").val(result["normalShiftPinCount"]);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert('Some error occurred!');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm text-center" id="normalShiftOaDiv" class="">
      <label for="currentOa">Current OA?</label><br>
      <input type="radio" name="currentOa" id="normalShiftOa" value="normalShiftOa">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm" id="normalShiftOperatorNameDiv">
      <label for="normalShiftOperator">Normal Shift</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="normalShiftOperator" name="normalShiftOperator">
        <option></option>
        <option>A</option>
        <option>B</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm" id="normalShiftOperatorDurationDiv">
      <label for="normalShiftOperatorDuration">Duration</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="normalShiftOperatorDuration" name="normalShiftOperatorDuration">
        <option></option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <label for="normalShiftPinCount">Pin Count</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="normalShiftPinCount" name="normalShiftPinCount" value="23">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <label for="normalShiftDate">Date</label>
      <input type="date" class="form-control" id="normalShiftDate" name="normalShiftDate">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 30px;" id="normalShiftUpdate" name="normalShiftUpdate">Update</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show the php variables `$normalShiftOa`, `$normalShiftOperatorDuration` and `$normalShiftPinCount` in the form fields with id `normalShiftOperator`, `normalShiftOperatorDuration`, `normalShiftPinCount` respectively when someone change calendar. Please see the contents of `supervisorEditAjax.php`. How can I show these three variables into the three `id` fields?

I only know how to show to one single field. But if there are multiple values to be shown in multiple fields, how can we do that?

Can someone please help?

**Edit 1**

Contents of `supervisorEditAjax.php`

```
<?php
$normalShiftOa = "A";
$normalShiftOperatorDuration = "2";
$normalShiftPinCount = "100";
$arr = array('normalShiftOa' => $normalShiftOa, 'normalShiftOperatorDuration' => $normalShiftOperatorDuration, 'normalShiftPinCount' => $normalShiftPinCount);
echo json_encode($arr);?>
```

I tried to use some Json method. But it is not working

Comment: _“Please see the contents of supervisorEditAjax.php.”_ - where?

Comment: In theory your code should do exactly as you're asking, from the bits we can see. If it isn't, please explain more specifically what issue occurs and where in the code? Do you get some error message and/or unexpected behavior? Please explain the problem with your specific, rather than simply asking vaguely "how" to do something which you appear to already have done.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry. Forgot to add that

Comment: @ADyson Basically it is not showing anything. Do I need to use some other technique to show multiple values in multiple fields?

Comment: You can not just output three values one after another, and then still expect to be able to access individual parts using `result["normalShiftOa"]`. This should use JSON, only you don’t want to `return` it (where to?), you want to `echo` the JSON.

Comment: @Anu now you've shown the PHP, it's clear what the problem is. You've just echoed 3 values one after another. So let's say the values are "x", "123" and "abc". The response which jQuery sees will simply say "x123abc". All one big string. No names attached to any of it. How do you imagine it is going to be able to read specific items from that? There's no chance. You haven't really considered what your output will look like, I don't think. As CBroe says, you need to make an associative array of your values in the PHP, and then encode that variable as JSON, so you get structured output.

Comment: Do you have any sample that has similar scenario that I could refer to get a better idea?

Comment: As you can see, I tried something with Json too. But I couldn't get it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trial and error, I am able to show it in the respective form fields. The issue was at the Ajax part. Basically I need to parse the Json object in order to get the specific values. Replace the AJAX code as below and it works fine

```js
< script >
  $("#normalShiftDate").change(function() {
    var FD = new FormData($('#dailyEditor')[0]);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "supervisorEditAjax.php",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      data: FD,
      success: function(result) {
        var returnedData = JSON.parse(result); //This is the change done to the code
        $('#normalShiftOperator').val(returnedData["normalShiftOa"]);
        $("#normalShiftOperatorDuration").val(returnedData["normalShiftOperatorDuration"]);
        $("#normalShiftPinCount").val(returnedData["normalShiftPinCount"]);
      },
      error: function() {
        alert('Some error occurred!');
      }
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

Please read more about JSON.parse [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)